Circuit schema 2 ways WS2812 connect with 1 PCB layout
Hey all I am having a difficut time trying to figure out how to go about the following:
I am wanting to just make 1 pcb but I am using WS2812B LEDs and therefore needs to be in the correct direction.
My current schema of this is below which I do not think is correct:

Basically If i start from the left side then it would be:
IN->OUT->IN->OUT->IN->OUT->DONE
And vis-versa:
OUT->IN->OUT->IN->OUT->IN->DONE
Visually this would look like this:

So I am not sure what the correct way to wire them up in the schema that would function the way I am wanting to do it?
So to recap - just want to be able to use 1 PCB that will do both left and right connections for the WS2812B LEDs.
Or would the best way to do this is to just rotate the pcb itself:

But I would rather do it in the schema itself if possible instead of just flipping the board.
UPDATE
After a few I think I managed to draw up the schematic correctly in order to use the same PCB in its normal orientation without the need to flip it upside down or have a 2nd pcb altogether.
This look good?


UPDATE #2
Here is the visual of what it would look like if I simply flipped the 2nd PCB:

Notice the LEDs do not align.
UPDATE #3
I re-measured the item the LEDs will be going on and came out with a PCB that looks the same either right-side up or flipped. :)


What's wrong with flipping the board? I presume you're going to make multiple copies of the same board and wire them up one row at a time.

both red/green diagrams are correct ... the schematic diagram does not match the red/green diagram

Just connect them as shown in the Datasheet, Typical application circuit (page 5), and you're golden. Your design is over-engineered and flawed.

Your updated schematic would work if "jumpered" correctly:
Left-to-right:

or
Rigth-to-left


But I seriously fail to see a benefit of this design, instead of simply "rotating" the PCB.
Cons:

extra manual steps are time consuming and increase the failure rate
you could easily damage components if "jumpered" incorrectly (mistakes do happen)
you have to keep track and be aware of the PCB configuration variants when installing a PCB (or replacing a defective one)

Pros:

the PCB isn't upside-down (yay! /s)


If it's just for a hobby project it really doesn't matter. Knock yourself out and have fun. But for a large scale production, I would recommend doing it the simple way.

Regarding UPDATE #2:
If you want the LEDs to align in either position, you have to place the LEDs accordingly.


I was looking at just doing the upside down version but the LEDs would not align correctly - its odd.

I updated my OP with UPDATE #2 showing you this.

Added another update to my OP. Thanks for helping me out @Velvet!
